# Plotting top 5 most frequent factors using R

Tags: r

In R I have a data frame f with headers a, b, c.  Column c has factor data.

plot(f$c) does this
[image: the bad plot]

How can I limit the plot to the top 5 most frequently occurring factors of column c in descending order?

The following works just fine:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds) # clarity is a good categorical variable
with(diamonds, barplot(rev(sort(table(clarity))[1:5])))
```

Is there a neat way to post this on SO after the fact?

[image]

Comment: could you pls paste the output of dput(your_data) ?

Comment: @Selden There is an option to migrate the whole question -- this could be done either by community voting to close or by asking a moderator to do this (for instance by using flag).

Answer (score 9):

This seems more of a question for [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/), but anyway:

EDIT: reproducible, and a lot simpler

```
f <- data.frame(c=factor(sample(rep(letters[1:8], 10),40)))
t <- table(f$c) # frequency of values in f$c
plot( sort(t, decreasing=TRUE)[1:5] ), type="h")
```

Comment: Nope but that's closer than I got.  They don't seem to be in order.

Comment: @Selden: ok, did not order. now look if that's better. Generally it helps when the original poster provides code.